# Is there a function like `cumreduce` along the lines of `numpy.cumsum` or `numpy.cumprod` in python?

Tags: python, numpy

When I need the sum or product of the elements in a list such as

```py
>>> foo = [10, 5, 3, 4]
```

I can use the `sum` or `prod` functions of numpy

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.sum(foo)
22

>>> np.prod(foo)
600
```

Likewise, when I need the cumulative sum or product, I can use `np.cumsum` or `np.cumprod`

```py
>>> np.cumsum(foo)
array([10, 15, 18, 22])

>>> np.cumprod(foo)
array([ 10,  50, 150, 600])
```

**Is there a way I can obtain the cumulative result of an arbitrary `reduce` operation?**

---

For example, if I had a function like

```py
def my_fn(a, b):
    return a + b**2
```

I could use `functools.reduce` to obtain

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(my_fn, foo)
60
```

**What I am looking for is a function which would give me the following**

```
>>> cumreduce(my_fn, foo)
[10, 35, 44, 60]
```

That is, each element of the result is equal to `reduce(my_fn, foo[:i])`.

---

Of course, I can do this in the naive way

```py
>>> def cumreduce(fn, seq):
...     return [reduce(fn, seq[:i]) for i in range(1, len(seq)+1)]

>>> cumreduce(my_fn, foo)
[10, 35, 44, 60]
```

Ideally I am looking for a built-in function with the same or similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, what you are looking for is `itertools.accumulate`:

```
import itertools

[*itertools.accumulate(foo,my_fn)]
# [10, 35, 44, 60]
```

Numpy ufuncs often have an accumulate method. Examples:

```
np.bitwise_xor.accumulate(foo)
array([10, 15, 12,  8])

np.add.accumulate(foo)
array([10, 15, 18, 22])
# cf. cumsum:
np.cumsum(foo)
array([10, 15, 18, 22]
```

Comment: is there something more generic? like defining a "zero" element, and a "+" operator?